Electron: I keep getting undefined value from the main process in renderer process
I keep getting undefined value from the main process in renderer process. I am using ipcRenderer.invoke and ipcMain.handle.
main process (just cut down to this section):
ipcMain.handle('process-message-to-gemini', async (event, chatMessage) => {
  const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyC30Qftd1JbdwZbMS_wbyoOhHtjza1pYOg'
  const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(API_KEY)
  const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: 'gemini-1.5-flash' })

  const prompt = chatMessage.message

  const result = await model.generateContent(prompt)
  const response = await result.response
  const text = response.text()
  console.log(text)
  return text
})

preload:
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from 'electron'
import { electronAPI } from '@electron-toolkit/preload'

// Custom APIs for renderer
const api = {
  processMessageToChatGPT: (chatMessages) => {
    ipcRenderer.invoke('process-message-to-chatgpt', chatMessages)
  },
  processMessageToGemini: (chatMessage) => {
    ipcRenderer.invoke('process-message-to-gemini', chatMessage)
  }
}

// Use `contextBridge` APIs to expose Electron APIs to
// renderer only if context isolation is enabled, otherwise
// just add to the DOM global.
if (process.contextIsolated) {
  try {
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', electronAPI)
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', api)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
} else {
  window.electron = electronAPI
  window.api = api
}

renderer process (just cut down to this section):
try {
      const response = await window.api.processMessageToGemini(newMessage);
      console.log(response)
      setMessages([...newMessages, {
        message: response,
        sender: "Gemini",
        direction: "incoming"
      }])
    } catch (error){
      console.error('Error:', error.message);
    } finally {
      setTyping(false)
    }

The response that I got in the renderer process is undefined. What am I doing wrong?
I expected to get text from gemini

I will vote to close this question as caused by a typo. You get undefined because your preload api functions don't return anything.

preload.js
Edit processMessageToGemini to return a value.
 processMessageToGemini: async (chatMessage) => {
    const result = await ipcRenderer.invoke('process-message-to-gemini', chatMessage)
    return result;
 }

